# Efecto zoom blur en canvas con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, canvas, transicion

estoy intentando crear un efecto "zoom blur" para crear una transición entre 2 canvas con css y javascript, pero lo único que he conseguido lograr hasta el momento es aplicar una transformación de tamaño (zoom) y un desenfoque, pero en cambio no logro aproximarme más al resultado de este efecto.

También he estado investigando y por la información que he recopilado, creo que se podría llegar a conseguir empleando transformaciones 3d de css pero la verdad es que no termino de encontrar información útil para lograrlo.

¿Alguien sabe como se podría lograr un efecto como este?
Muchisimas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]